# Problem with putting value in array in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to make array which put users in a time using for loop. For example:

> y[1]="user1"
>
> y[2]="user2"
>
> ...
>
> y[n]="usern"

I tried to do it like this

```
#!/bin/bash

x=$(who | cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq | wc -l)

for (( i=1; i<=$x; i++ )); do
        y[$i]=$(who | cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq | sed -n '$ip')
        p[$i]=$(lsof -u ${y[$i]} | wc -l)

        echo "Users:"
        echo ${y[$i]}
        echo -e "Number of launched files:\n" ${p[$i]}
done
```

Most likely I'm using command "sed" wrong. 
Can you help me?

Comment: It seems that you're appending the number to end of the user output. Try this: `y[$i]=$(who | cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq | sed "s/$/${ip}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed your `sed` command seems to be a bit off. I can't really guess what you're trying to do there. Besides that, I'm wondering why you're executing `who` twice. You can make use of the data first obtained in the following manner.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# define two arrays
y=()
p=()
#x=0

while read -r username; do
        y+=("$username")
        p+=($(lsof -u $(id -u "$username") | wc -l))

        echo -e "User:\n${y[-1]}"
        echo -e "Open files:\n${p[-1]}"

        # The -1 index is the last index in the array, but you
        # could uncomment the x=0 variable and the line below:
        #((x++))

done <<< $(who | cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq)

echo "Amount of users: $x"
exit 0
```

Comment: I'd also recommend double-quoting references to `$username`, just in case of weird characters.